# Better and Efficient way to Iterate through Data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop, if-statement

So, I've got two dataframes, one with 54k rows and 1 column and another with 139k rows and 3 columns, I need to check weather the values of a column from first dataframe lies in between values of two columns in second dataframe, and if they match, I need to replace that particular value with corresponding string value in the second dataframe into first dataframe.

I tried doing it with simple for loops and if else statements, but the number of iteration are huge and my cell is taking forever to run. I've attached some snippets down below, If there is any better way to rewrite that particular part of code, It would be great help. Thanks in advance.

First DataFrame:

```
ip_address_to_clean
IP_Address_clean
0   815237196
1   1577685417
2   979279225
3   3250268602
4   2103448748
... ...
54208   4145673247
54209   1344187002
54210   3156712153
54211   1947493810
54212   2872038579
54213 rows × 1 columns
```

Second DataFrame:

```
ip_boundaries_file
country lower_bound_ip_address_clean    upper_bound_ip_address_clean
0   Australia   16777216    16777471
1   China   16777472    16777727
2   China   16777728    16778239
3   Australia   16778240    16779263
4   China   16779264    16781311
... ... ... ...
138841  Hong Kong   3758092288  3758093311
138842  India   3758093312  3758094335
138843  China   3758095360  3758095871
138844  Singapore   3758095872  3758096127
138845  Australia   3758096128  3758096383
138846 rows × 3 columns
```

Code I've written :

```
ip_address_to_clean_copy = ip_address_to_clean.copy()
o_ip = ip_address_to_clean['IP_Address_clean'].values
l_b = ip_boundaries_file['lower_bound_ip_address_clean'].values

for i in range(len(o_ip)):
    for j in range(len(l_b)):
        if (ip_address_to_clean['IP_Address_clean'][i] > ip_boundaries_file['lower_bound_ip_address_clean'][j]) and          (ip_address_to_clean['IP_Address_clean'][i] < ip_boundaries_file['upper_bound_ip_address_clean'][j]):
            ip_address_to_clean_copy['IP_Address_clean'][i] = ip_boundaries_file['country'][j]
            #print(ip_address_to_clean_copy['IP_Address_clean'][i])
    #print(i)
```

Comment: The way you're doing it is in O(np) (n and p being the sizes of the 2 dfs). I can think of a very easy (though not memory efficient) way to turn it O(n + p): reading from the 2nd dataframe, create a list `replacement` of size 3758096383, and assign to each cell from index 16777216 to 16777471 the relevant string and so on; then in your first dataframe, you just have to replace `value` with `replacement[value]`.

Comment: I just had another idea, since the 2nd df seems to be ordered: if it actually is, a dichotomy search on the rows might allow to turn the time efficiency into O(n log(p) ) without the need to consume memory.

Answer (score 0):

This works (I tested it on small tables).

```
replacement1 = [None]*3758096384
replacement2 = []
for _, row in ip_boundaries_file.iterrows():
    a,b,c = row['lower_bound_ip_address_clean'], row['upper_bound_ip_address_clean'], row['country']
    replacement1[a+1:b]=[len(replacement2)]*(b-a-1)
    replacement2.append(c)
    
ip_address_to_clean_copy['IP_Address_clean'] = ip_address_to_clean_copy['IP_Address_clean'].apply(lambda x:replacement2[replacement1[x]] if (x < len(replacement1) and replacement1[x]!=None) else x)
```

I tweaked the lambda function to keep the original ip if it's not in the replacement table.

Notes:

- Compared to my comment, I added the `replacement2` table to hold the actual strings, and put the indexes in `replacement1` to make it more memory efficient.
- This is based on one of the methods to sort a list in O(n) when you know the contained values are bounded.

Example:

Inputs:

```
ip_address_to_clean = pd.DataFrame([10,33,2,179,2345,123], columns = ['IP_Address_clean'])

ip_boundaries_file = pd.DataFrame([['China',1,12],
                                   ['Australia', 20,40],
                                   ['China',2000,3000],
                                   ['France', 100,150]],
                                  columns = ['country', 'lower_bound_ip_address_clean',
                                             'upper_bound_ip_address_clean'])
```

Output:

```
ip_address_to_clean_copy
# Out[13]: 
#   IP_Address_clean
# 0            China
# 1        Australia
# 2            China
# 3              179
# 4            China
# 5           France
```

As I mentioned in another comment, here's another script that performs a dichotomy search on the 2nd DataFrame; it works in O(n log(p)), which is slower than the above script, but consumes far less memory!

```
def replace(n, df):
    if len(df) == 0:
        return n
    i = len(df)//2
    if df.iloc[i]['lower_bound_ip_address_clean'] < n <  df.iloc[i]['upper_bound_ip_address_clean']:
        return df.iloc[i]['country']
    elif len(df) == 1:
        return n
    else:
        if n <= df.iloc[i]['lower_bound_ip_address_clean']:
            return replace(n, df.iloc[:i-1])
        else:
            return replace(n, df.iloc[i+1:])
        
ip_address_to_clean_copy['IP_Address_clean'] = ip_address_to_clean['IP_Address_clean'].apply(lambda x: replace(x,ip_boundaries_file))
```

Comment: Now of course, a 4 gigacells list is probably a bit extreme as far as memory inefficiency goes; using a dictionary instead of a list for `replacement1` would probably be better.

Comment: Hey Swifty, thanks for the input but I'm getting an error stating:
----> 8 ip_address_to_clean_copy['IP_Address_clean'] = ip_address_to_clean_copy['IP_Address_clean'].apply(lambda x:replacement2[replacement1[x]] if replacement1[x]!=None else x)

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Is it possible there are ips in the 1st dataframe that are greater than 3758096383 ? I forgot to take that into account. I'll modifiy the lambda function for this. Done, try this new version.